# Averaging dstat output

Tags: netstat, iostat

I need to average upload and download speed using `dstat -n`.

How can I add all the received and sent datas that appear after `dstat -n`, so that I can add them and find average upload and download speed over some period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the arguments for delay (number of seconds) and counter (number of times) to run, and capture the output in a txt or csv file.

Check the dstat manual (see arguments section):

http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/dstat.1.html

```
dstat -n 5 10 >> /tmp/dstat_speed.txt
```

The above runs 10 times for every 5 seconds.

Comment: I know that.Give me the way to add them,not print to a file.

Comment: Okay found it,adding columns in a file,using this method

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it.
Let's say we need to average it for "2 min(120 sec)".
First write it to a file named stat.txt.Refresh every second fro 120 times.

```
       dstat -n 1 120 >> stat.txt
```

Add the columns of stat.txt

```
       awk -F" " '{t1=t1+$1;t2=t2+$2}END{t1=t1/120;t2=t2/120;print t1"\t"t2}' stat.txt
```

Remove stat.txt

```
       rm stat.txt
```

We can make a script too from these commands.